# What is the concept of 'DefaultHttpContext' in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I am searching for understanding the concept of **DefaultHttpContext**. What is this in simple terms?

There is a sample code below:

```
           var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "E59899E9-AAFD-4AA6-B32E-12A27A4FA43D"),
                                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "example@mail.ir")
                                        // other required and custom claims
                                   }, "TestAuthentication"));

            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
            {
                User = user
            };


            /// passed a ControllerContext which defines the controller to be created
            controllerContext = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext()
            {
                HttpContext = httpContext,
            };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "concept"?

Comment: @Dai What is usage of **DefaultHttpContext** here?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar. Yes the snippet code is a part of Unit test class

Comment: So what is your question? I'm struggling to understand what information you require.

Comment: [HttpConcept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext) is an abstract class, this one you have to implement in a derived class. `DefaultHttpContext` is the default ASP.net implementation. You can write your own,  e.g. for unit tests

Comment: The `DefaultHttpContext` class is the default implementation of the abstract `HttpContext` class that is included in ASP.NET Core.
**HttpContext Initializes** a new instance of the DefaultHttpContext class.

**"When an HTTP request arrives at the server, the server processes the request and builds an HttpContext object. This object represents the request which your application code can use to create the response"**

Comment: Above comments are correct. A simple example where you can eject this to your controllers or apply in your test units: Get/Set Http Headers, read URL parameters for SEO validation (...)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron ,As you mentioned, it's simulate a request for controller with **ClaimsIdentity** required. thank you very much.

Comment: below link can be useful for more study 
https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/unit-testing-the-httpcontext-in-controllers

thanks for all comments

Comment: DefaultHttpContext has its own page on learn.microsoft.com. Therefore the question seems to be  please read the documentation for me and explain, which is not what this site is for. Consider rephrasing after trying to do what you wish in your unit test, if it fails describe what you want to do and ask how to do that explicit task and you will see many more helpful hands

Comment: @T. Nielsen  I read docs.micosoft.com first of all, but wasn't helpful. so i was trying to ask question to use other people knowledge and experience.

Comment: i you can rephrase like "i want to write a unit test which does this..." i have tried to do like that ... can somebody suggest how to achieve this because what i have tried didn't work e.g. people will be more likely to help. after all if people redescribe from the same source will it be helpful? and is your question really how should i understand  defaulthttpcontext or is it how do i do X in a unit test, if it is the first @JHBonarius has already suggested your path ahead. It is a sketchy field to emulate a hosting context in unit test of a controller, because it then is not hosted

Comment: Yes. you are right.

Comment: @MJavadSalehi You are welcome, does that answer your concern?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron. Thank you. your answer give me a lots of view and help me to understand about moqing dependcies of controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is DefaultHttpContext**

The `DefaultHttpContext` class is the default implementation of the abstract `HttpContext` class that is included in ASP.NET Core.

**What is the concept of 'DefaultHttpContext' in ASP.NET Core?**

Actually, `HttpContext Initializes` a new instance of the `DefaultHttpContext` class. "When an HTTP request arrives at the server, the server processes the request and builds an HttpContext object. This object represents the request which your application code can use to create the response".

**Note:** You can have a look more details at the [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0).